# Where to put function declaration?

Tags: c++, function, coding-style, encapsulation

Let's say I'm developing a logging functionality. Inside `logging.h` I declare the function to be used by the application later on.

```cpp
// logging.h

#include <string>

namespace logging {

void LogThis(const std::string& text);

};  // namespace logging
```

Its definition is obviously inside `logging.cpp`:

```cpp
// logging.cpp

void logging::LogThis(const std::string& text) {
  std::cout << "Log: " << text << '\n';
}
```

Now lets pretent that my `LogThis` function's work is split up into some smaller helper functions. They're not part of the logging interface. Let's take a `Prettify` function as an example.

```cpp
// logging.cpp

void logging::LogThis(const std::string& text) {
  Prettify(text);
  std::cout << "Log: " << text << '\n';
}
```

**My question is: Where do I put the function declaration of `Prettify`?** I shouldn't include it in the `logging.h` header file, because then it can be called by other compilation units and its not part of the interface. So just put it inside `logging.cpp` instead like this?

```cpp
// logging.cpp

namespace logging {

void Prettify(std::string& ugly_text);

void LogThis(const std::string& text) {
  Prettify(text);
  std::cout << "Log: " << text << '\n';
}

void Prettify(std::string& ugly_text) {
  // making it pretty...
}

}
```

I'm looking for some best practices / rules of thumb / opinions on this :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well would other translation units want to use it?

Comment: No, Prettify is only used by this logging translation unit.

Comment: Put it in an anonymous namespace in logging.cpp

Comment: @JesperJuhl What is the advantage of putting in in an anonymous namespace instead of the `logging` namespace?

Comment: Side note: If you place the definition of `Prettify` above the definition of `LogThis` you can remove the need for a separate declaration.

Comment: @user4581301 That would become pretty messy though once there are multiple (let's say 4-5) helper functions though, right? Having to figure out the order in which to put them inside the file.

Comment: It can be and you may have circular dependencies among the functions that make it impossible. The reason I prefer it is I have one less place to make a change if the function prototype changes. I find linker or compiler errors stemming from updating one but not both  more annoying than making sure the functions are ordered. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 4):

For things that are *only* needed within the file, I would just place it in an anonymous namespace within the C++ file itself, sort of the modern equivalent of the legacy C `static` keyword on functions<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
namespace {
    void WeaveMagic(std::string& ugly_text) {
        WeaveMoreMagic(ugly_text);
    }
    void Prettify(std::string& ugly_text) {
        WeaveMagic(ugly_text);
    }
}
```

If you place this before any use of the functions, and ensure a strict hierarchy of calls, you can skip the declarations since the definitions provides the required information, as shown above.

Of course, if there are any *circular* dependencies between multiple anonymous functions (i.e., circular recursion), you will still need to provide declarations:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    int DivThree(int val); // needed to implement AddOne()

    int AddOne(int val) {
        std::cout << "AddOne " << val << " -> " << (val + 1) << '\n';
        if (val > 0) return DivThree(val + 1);
        return val;
    }

    int DivThree(int val) {
        std::cout << "DivThree " << val << " -> " << (val / 3) << '\n';
        return AddOne(val / 3);
    }
}

int main(){
    int final = AddOne(18);
    std::cout << "Final " << final << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And, yes, that's *very* contrived, but good examples of circular recursion are few and far between :-) The output is:

```
AddOne 18 -> 19
DivThree 19 -> 6
AddOne 6 -> 7
DivThree 7 -> 2
AddOne 2 -> 3
DivThree 3 -> 1
AddOne 1 -> 2
DivThree 2 -> 0
AddOne 0 -> 1
Final 0
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup>  CPP Core Guidline SF.22 actually covers this:

> Use an unnamed (anonymous) namespace for all internal/non-exported entities.
>
> Reason: Nothing external can depend on an entity in a nested unnamed namespace. Consider putting every definition in an implementation source file in an unnamed namespace unless that is defining an "external/exported" entity.
>
> An API class and its members can't live in an unnamed namespace; but any "helper" class or function that is defined in an implementation source file should be at an unnamed namespace scope.

Comment: Important to understand that this gives the name internal linkage, compared to OP's code which gave it external linkage (and therefore potentially causing ODR violation with some other external linkage symbol Prettify)

Comment: I just noticed that there is even a Cpp Core Guidelines for that: SF.22

Comment: @paxdiablo Let's say I have 4-5 helper functions. Would I open up an anonymous namespace, then write the 4-5 function declarations, then the 4-5 function definitions?

Comment: @Lexusminds: no, just put the anon namespace at the top. I usually put it between includes and externally-visible code. If you do that, the definitions provide the declaration.

Comment: @paxdiablo That won't work if the helper functions might call each other though, right? Then the order is important or function declarations are needed.

Comment: @Lexusminds - The only requirement to call a function (that is not a class member) is that it be previously declared.  A function definition is a type of function declaration (which also implements the function).  If a function is called before it is defined, then there must also be a declaration before the point where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are operating on functions only, as @paxdiablo have written, you can use anonymous namespace (look at his answer).

I have some C-based habits, so personally I would also see it as `static` function. But I'm not sure how C++ fanatics will look at it :). `static` (in this context) makes functions local for compilation unit (logging.cpp), so it cannot be linked from outside.

```
//logging.cpp

static void Prettify(std::string& ugly);

void LogThis(const std::string& text) {
  Prettify(text);
  std::cout << "Log: " << text << '\n';
}

static void Prettify(std::string& ugly) { }
```

However if your logging utility would be object-oriented. I suggest you to use D-pointer and Q-Pointer design pattern (known also as PImpl idiom) - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl .

```
//logging.h
#include <string>

class loggingImpl;

class logging {
public :
   logging();
   virtual ~logging();
   void LogThis(const std::string& text);

protected :
   loggingImpl *impl;
};

//logging.cpp
class loggingImpl
{
public :
   loggingImpl(logging *p) : qptr(p) { }

   void Prettify(std::string& ugly) { }
   //anything what you need and should be hided
   // access parent through qptr
protected :
   logging *qptr;
};

logging::logging() : impl(new loggingImpl) { }

logging::~logging() { delete impl; }

void logging::LogThis(const std::string& text) {
  impl->Prettify(text);
  std::cout << "Log: " << text << '\n';
}
```

As you have written, putting declaration in header file is not proper due to limiting visibility of unused symbols.

Comment: We're *fanatics,* it should be obvious how we'll look at it :-)